# recursive function not getting call in jquery while creating anchor tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically creating a data table where there will be different tabs added as per object is passed.

While the tabs are getting created but switching is not happening because the call created by `onclick` function is not getting called.

here is code example and screenshot below:

```
aTag = $("<a href='#' onclick='nGActiveSheet="+nTabs+";makeView1("+ data +");'>"+sCurrTab+"</a>");
```

[image: screenshot with error]

The `makeView1` function is accepting one parameter as object

Comment: we may need to see more of your code, the error suggests that the `onclick` handler fires correctly but the function `makeView1` is not defined at this point. `makeView1` should be defined before you set the event handler. Also you'll probably have some trouble with your `data` parameter, if it's an object, you can't concatenate it to a string, as `[object Object]` will be concatenated to the string instead of its value

Comment: @Kaddath :  the Method makeView1 is one in which this tag is being called recursively and even if I stringify the object as passed in mani call , I am getting the error as makeView1 is not identified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type javascript code directly in the `onclick` attribute of an element, it is executed in the global scope. It will then loose all references to local variables.

In your case it's probably that `makeView1` is not global, and therefore not defined when all is executed in the global scope.

Consider following snippet: `makeView1` and `test` both exist in the gloabal scope as well as locally in the IIFE (immediately invoked function expression). But when you click on the link, you can see it's the global function which is called, and the global `test` variable which is used (you can click twice to verify the value has been set to 1.

You'll also notice that `data` is not passed correctly, when it is concatenated to  string in the attribute, `[object Object]` is used.

```js
var test = "global";
var data = { foo: 'global' };
function makeView1(_data){
    console.log('global: ', _data);
    console.log('test: ', test);
}

(function(){
    var test = "local";
    var data = { foo: 'local' };
    function makeView1(_data){
        console.log('local: ', _data);
        console.log('test: ', test);
    }
    
    aTag = $('<a href="#" onclick="makeView1(\''+ data +'\');test=1;">TEST</a>');
    aTag.appendTo('body');
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It's much better in this case to use the jQuery way yo attach event handlers with the `on('click', function)` syntax. This way, the handler function will "remember" the scope from where it is created, and so you are not stuck with global variables.

You'll get rid of the object's conversion to string at the same time because you don't build a string for the onclick anymore, but rather attach a proper function handler to the event:

```js
var test = "global";
var data = { foo: 'global' };
function makeView1(_data){
    console.log('global: ', _data);
    console.log('test: ', test);
}

(function(){
    var test = "local";
    var data = { foo: 'local' };
    function makeView1(_data){
        console.log('local: ', _data);
        console.log('test: ', test);
    }
    
    aTag = $('<a href="#">TEST</a>');
    aTag.on('click', function(e){
        makeView1(data);
        test = 1;
    });
    aTag.appendTo('body');
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```